# What is the difference between "Rücksichtnahme" and "Rücksicht"?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to understand the difference between those two, I think "Rücksicht" means hindsight. When I look [HERE](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/ruecksichtnahme) for "Rücksichtnahme" they refer me to "Rücksicht".

Comment: It's not hindsight. This is a false friend.

Comment: "Hindsight" is not Rücksicht. Maybe "Rückblick" would be more appropriate? Rücksicht is "caution". Maybe you got confused about the meaning of the English word "hindsight"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word **Rücksichtnahme** is made from the verb phrase *Rücksicht nehmen*.

> Der Autofahrer **nahm** keine **Rücksicht** auf die Fußgänger.

*The car driver did not take regard of the pedestrians.*

That sentence would not work with *Rücksichtnahme*, because there's already the *nehmen* inside it.

> <s>Der Autofahrer nahm keine Rücksichtnahme auf die Fussgänger.</s>

But if somebody is referring to the verb phrase *Rücksicht nehmen*, the word *Rücksichtnahme* fits perfectly.

> Die Polizei sprach von einem groben Fall fehlender Rücksichtnahme im Straßenverkehr.

*Police called it a severe case of regardless driving.*

Though *Rücksicht* would work here, too, Germans love to use nouns made from verb phrases. You will encounter such nouns very often.

Comment: "Rücksichtnahme" can often mean the same as "Rücksicht", used exchangeable, a more blown up, baroque form, a bit ugly as well. 
But it can also be the real abstraction. While "Fehlende Rücksicht" sound good referring to a particular situation, "mangelnde Rücksichtnahme" fits well in a description of a personality trait or a general tendency in sorciety.   I love Janka's example for that use.